multi indexed recurrence relations
A recurrence relation is an equation which defines the nth term of a sequence $a_n$ in terms of some previous terms. More generally, one might consider $a$ to be indexed by the n-dimensional grid $\mathbb{Z}^n$. For example:
$$ a_{n,m} = a_{n-1,m}+a_{n,m-1}$$
I'd like to know what this is called, and where I can read more about such recurrence relations.

The type of recurrence relation you are referring to is called a partial recurrence relation or recurrence relation on a grid.
I may suggest "Concrete Mathematics" by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik: This book provides insight into various recurrence relations, including multidimensional ones.

The most accurate term would probably be "multivariate recurrence". However, for usual we analyze instead the corresponding generating function, so you'll have more luck looking for "multivariate generating function".
More specifically, your case is a linear bivariate recurrence with constant coefficients.
Generally, one should be familiar with the univariate case (i.e. recurrence with only one index) before diving in the multivariate case, as it gets quite messy.
The most fitting paper for your question would probably be
Linear recurrences with constant coefficients: the multivariate case.
